# Pagination using category from mysql not working

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am trying to fetch data from mysql and display them category wise with pagination. I am geting the category wise result but in pagination i am seeing duplicate result from second page onwards

Have a look at [link:](http://www.simadimakeupguru.com/gallery1.php)

When I click on the category it is working. But see the pagination. The last pages are blank. I want to display picture category wise. Suppose when i click on bridal it will display only bridal picture. I am having two tables i.e. category and album. In category I have id and cname and in the album I have id, cid, thumbnail, picture. The cid is coming from the category table and actually is the id of the category table

Here is the code

```
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM `category` WHERE `id`='$_GET[cat_id]'";
$sql=mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
     {
    ?>
    <div class="container">
     <h3><?="$row[cname]"; }?></h3>
    <?php 
//================paging============================================
if($_GET[page_no])
{
    $page_no=$_GET[page_no];
}else{
    $page_no=1;
}

if($_POST[page])
{
$upper_limit = $_POST[page];

}else{
    if($_GET[upper_limit])
    {
        $upper_limit = $_GET[upper_limit];

    }else
        {

    $upper_limit = 21;

    }
}

$lower_limit = $upper_limit * ($page_no - 1);


$sql2="SELECT * FROM `album` WHERE `id`='$_GET[cat_id]'";
$res2=mysql_query($sql2);
$num=mysql_num_rows($res2);

$num_of_page = intval($num/$upper_limit);

if($num%$upper_limit!=0)
{
    $num_of_page = $num_of_page + 1;
}
//==================================================================
$count=$lower_limit;
$c=1;
$sel = "SELECT * FROM `album` ORDER BY  id DESC LIMIT $lower_limit , $upper_limit";     
$res=mysql_query($sel); 
$num=mysql_num_rows($res);
if($num!="")
{
    $sel="SELECT * FROM `album` WHERE `cid`='$_GET[cat_id]'";
    $tab=mysql_query($sel);
while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($tab))
{            
        print "<a class='fancybox-buttons' data-fancybox-group='button' href='admin/$row1[picture]'><img src='admin/$row1[thumbnail]' /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
$c++;       
}
?>
```

```
<?php

//=======================================================================
    $prev = $page_no - 1;
    $next = $page_no + 1;
print "<center><TABLE >
<TR>
    <TD  align='center'>";
    if($page_no!=1)
        {
            print "<a href='gallery-cat-photo.php?page_no=$prev&upper_limit=$upper_limit'><font size='' color='#660066'>Previous</font></a>&nbsp;";
        }
    for($i=1; $i<=$num_of_page; $i++)
    {
        if($page_no==$i)
        {
        print "&nbsp;<span class='title'><font size='' color='#ff0099'>( $i )</font></span>&nbsp;";

        }else{
        print "&nbsp;<a href='gallery-cat-photo.php?page_no=$i&upper_limit=$upper_limit'><font size='' color='#009933'>$i</font></a>&nbsp;";
        }
    }
    if($page_no!=$num_of_page)
    {
        print "&nbsp;<a href='gallery-cat-photo.php?page_no=$next&upper_limit=$upper_limit'><font size='' color='#660066'>Next</font></a>";
    }   
    //========================================================================
    print "</TD>
</TR></TABLE></center>
";
}
else
{
    print "<BR><h3><marquee behavior='alternate'><CENTER><FONT SIZE='3' COLOR='#ff0000'><B><I>There are no photos</I></B></FONT></CENTER></marquee></h3>";
}
?>
```

Changed the code to the following but still giving the same error

```
<?php
    /*
        Place code to connect to your DB here.
    */
    include('admin/lib/connection.php');    // include your code to connect to DB.

    $tbl_name="album";      //your table name
    // How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
    $adjacents = 3;

    /* 
       First get total number of rows in data table. 
       If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
    */
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name WHERE `cid`='$_GET[cat_id]'";
    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total_pages = $total_pages[num];

    /* Setup vars for query. */
    $targetpage = "gallery-cat-photo.php";  //your file name  (the name of this file)
    $limit = 21;                                //how many items to show per page
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if($page) 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
    else
        $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

    /* Get data. */
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE `cid`='$_GET[cat_id]' LIMIT $start, $limit";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    /* Setup page vars for display. */
    if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

    /* 
        Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
        We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
    */
    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
        //previous button
        if ($page > 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">? previous</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">? previous</span>"; 

        //pages 
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
        {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //in middle; hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
            }
        }

        //next button
        if ($page < $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next ?</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next ?</span>";
        $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
    }
?>

    <?php
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {

        // Your while loop here
    print "<figure class='photo2 element view'><a class='fancybox-buttons' data-fancybox-group='button' href='admin/$row[picture]'><img src='admin/$row[thumbnail]' /></a></figure>";
        }
    ?>


    </div>





<?=$pagination?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try like pagination like this, just pass your required parameters.

```
$per_page = 30;

$start = $_GET['start'];

$record_count = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from categories"));

$max_pages = $record_count / $per_page;

if  (!$start)
    $start = 0;

$get = mysql_query("select * from categories limit $start, $per_page");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
{
    $id = $row['cat_id'];
    $name = $row['cat_name'];

    echo $id." (".$name.")<br />";

}

$prev = $start - $per_page;
$next = $start + $per_page;

if(!($start<=0))
    echo "<a href='paging.php?start=$prev' style='text-decoration:none'>Previous</a>";

    $i=1;

    for ($x=0;$x<$record_count;$x=$x+$per_page)
{
    if($start!=$x)
        echo "<a href='paging.php?start=$x' style='text-decoration:none'>&nbsp;$i&nbsp;</a>";
    else
        echo "<a href='paging.php?start=$x' style='text-decoration:none'>&nbsp;<b>$i</b>&nbsp;</a>";
    $i++;
}

if(!($start>=$record_count-$per_page))
    echo "<a href='paging.php?start=$next' style='text-decoration:none'>Next</a>";
```

Comment: No this does not solve. I want to display picture category wise. Suppose when i click on bridal it will display only bridal picture. I am having two tables i.e. category and album. In category I have id and cname and in the album I have id, cid, thumbnail, picture. The cid is coming from the category table and actually is the id of the category table.

Comment: i used the following but same problem 
$record_count = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from album"));

$max_pages = $record_count / $per_page;

if  (!$start)
    $start = 0;

$get = mysql_query("select * from album where `cid`='S_GET[cat_id]' limit $start, $per_page");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
{
   
    print "<figure class='photo2 element view'><a class='fancybox-buttons' data-fancybox-group='button' href='admin/$row[picture]'><img src='admin/$row[thumbnail]' /></a></figure>";
}

Comment: @user3785303 cant get you. what should i do

Comment: For Example, 
- First, you need to fetch all records with pagination.
- When i click on bridal tab, you need to call ajax to refresh same page with bridal category so you can see all bridal images with pagination.
- you need to set dynamic condition for category which you want to show.